# Many to many relationship and drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dropdownlist as follows

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Categories, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Categories, new SelectList(Model.CategoriesDropDownList), "Choose a category", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Categories)
</div>
```

However, I get an invalid error for validation when I check if the model state is valid or not.

My product form view model is as follows

```
using LaptopMart.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace LaptopMart.ViewModels
{
public class ProductFormViewModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Stock")]
    public int? StockQuantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Category")]
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }


    public string Image { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Category> CategoriesDropDownList { get; set; }

}
}
```

I have a many to many relationship between category and product. When I want to fill up the form for product, I wish to choose a category from CategoriesDropDownList into Categories. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @KrishnrajRana Yes that's right

Comment: You cannot bind a dropdownlist to a collection of complex object (which is what `Categories` is) - a dropdownlists bind to and posts back a simple value

Comment: And your `new SelectList(Model.CategoriesDropDownList)` would never work! - suggest you refer [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for the code to generate a dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

You have specified wrong model type to your `@Html.DropDownListFor`. What i mean to say is type of the `Categories` properties should not be `ICollection<Category>`. When you use `DropDownListFor` - the first parameter is the property where your selected value is stored once you submit the form. So, in your case, it should be `CategoryId` which should be of type int. So after modification your code look like this -

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.CategoriesDropDownList, "CategoryId", "CategoryName"), "Choose a category", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and your model -

```
[Required]
[Display(Name="Category")]
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
```

Comment: I am new asp.net. So, what if a product can belong to multiple categories?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DropDownList` for one to one, and you can you `ListBox` for one to many.

I dont know your DB model but firstly you need change your ProductFormViewModel class. Because `public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }` and `public IEnumerable<Category> CategoriesDropDownList { get; set; }` are same.

It could be such as below

```
public class ProductFormViewModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Stock")]
    public int? StockQuantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Category")]
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }


    public string Image { get; set; }
    //one to one
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    //one to many
    public IEnumerable<int> CategoryIDS { get; set; }

}
```

Category class such as

```
public class Category{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

DropdownList example

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryID, new SelectList(Model.Categories , "CategoryId", "CategoryName"), "Choose a category", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Listbox  example

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.CategoryIDs, new SelectList(Model.Categories , "CategoryId", "CategoryName"), "Choose a category", new { @class = "form-control" })
```